# Yacc program giving error:"syntax error"

Tags: c, bison, yacc, lex, text-parsing

I have the following config file that I need to parse.

```
[ main ]
e_type=0x1B
```

The lex(test.l) and yacc(test.y) files are given below

test.l

```
%option noyywrap
%option yylineno
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "y.tab.h"

int yylinenu = 1;
int yycolno=1;

/**
 * Forward declerations
 **/
void Number ();
void HexaNumber ();
unsigned char getHexaLex (char c);
unsigned int strtol16 (char * str);


%}

%option nounput
%option noinput
%option case-insensitive

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------
   Some macros (standard regular expressions)
------------------------------------------------------------------*/

DIGIT       [0-9]
HEXALETTER  [a-fA-F]
HEXANUMBER  [0][x](({DIGIT}|{HEXALETTER})+)
NUM         {DIGIT}+
HEXA        ({DIGIT}|{HEXALETTER}|[*])
STR         \"[^\"]*\"
WSPACE      [ \t]*
NEWLINE     [\n\r]        

/*----------------------------------------------------------------
   The lexer rules
------------------------------------------------------------------*/
%%

e_type                   { yylval.str = yytext; return T_E_TYPE; }
main                     { yylval.str = yytext; return T_MAIN_SECTION;}
{HEXANUMBER}             { yylval.n = atoi(yytext);  HexaNumber(); return T_NUMBER; }
=                        { return T_EQUAL; }
"["                      { return T_OPEN_BRACKET; }
"]"                      { return T_CLOSE_BRACKET;}

[^\t\n\r]                { }
{WSPACE}                 { } /* whitespace: (do nothing) */
{NEWLINE}                {  
                            yylinenu++;
                            return T_EOL;
                         }

%%

void Number () {
    yylval.n = atol(yytext);
}
```

test.y

```
%{
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include "y.tab.h"
#include "lex.h"

#define E_PARSE_DEBUG
#ifdef E_PARSE_DEBUG
// Some yacc (bison) defines
#define YYDEBUG 1       // Generate debug code; needed for YYERROR_VERBOSE
#define YYERROR_VERBOSE // Give a more specific parse error message 
#endif

#define E_DEBUG_STRINGIFY(x) #x
#define E_DEBUG_TOSTRING(x) E_DEBUG_STRINGIFY(x)
#define E_DEBUG_AT (__FILE__ ":" E_DEBUG_TOSTRING(__LINE__))

extern  int yyparse (void);
extern int yylinenu;
extern int yycolno;
void yyerror(const char *str)
{
  fprintf(stderr,"line: %d column: %d error: %s %s \n",yylinenu,yycolno,str,yylval.str);
}

int yywrap()
{
  return 1;
}

int main()
{
  printf("> "); 

  // open a file handle to a particular file:
  FILE *myfile = fopen("tmp.conf", "r");
  // make sure it is valid:
  if (!myfile) {
      printf("I can't open tmp.conf \n");
      return -1;
  }else
  {
    printf("opened config file \n");
  }
  // set lex to read from it instead of defaulting to STDIN:
  yyin = myfile;

  yyparse();

  return 0;
}
int lineno = 0;
%}

/*------------------------------------------------------------------
  Yacc declarations
------------------------------------------------------------------ */

/* The structure for passing value between lexer and parser */
/* In the lexer we know it by the name 'yylval'*/
%union {
   char *str;
   unsigned int n;
   void * distr;
   void * command;
}

%token T_E_TYPE T_HOSTID_TYPE T_MAIN_SECTION T_EQUAL T_OPEN_BRACKET T_CLOSE_BRACKET T_EOL
%token <str> STRING
%token <n> T_NUMBER
%type <n> number


%%
config_file
    : /* empty */
    {

    }
    | config_file config_file_section
    {

    }
    ;

config_file_section
    : T_OPEN_BRACKET T_MAIN_SECTION T_CLOSE_BRACKET attribute_list
    {

    }
    ; 

attribute_list
    : /* empty */
    {

    }
    | attribute_list attribute_pair
    {

    }
    ;
attribute_pair
    : T_E_TYPE T_EQUAL number
    {

    }
    ;

number
    : T_NUMBER
    {

    }
    ;
%%
```

I have an include `lex.h` file that is included in test.y

```
#ifndef _LEX_H_
#define _LEX_H_

#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef _LEX_CPP_
int lineno = 1; // line number count; this will be used for error messages later
#else
   // Import some variables
extern int lineno;
extern FILE *yyin;  // the input stream

// Function prototype
int yylex ();
#endif
```

## endif

I compile the files as follows.

```
flex test.l
yacc -d  test.y
gcc lex.yy.c y.tab.c -Wall  -ll -o test -ldag
```

The binary `test` that I get is giving

```
> opened config file 
line: 1 column: 1 error: syntax error main
```

Comment: `HEXANUMBER` in your `.l` file needs to be surrounded by `{}`

Comment: @o11c - why is that?

Comment: @o11c - tried that still I get the same error

Comment: @o11c No it doesn't, unless it is used in a meta-expression context with ? or + or * and he us using *lex(1).*

Comment: First you need to trace which token you're getting the syntax error at. Include `yytext` in your syntax error message.

Comment: NB You only need to call `yyparse()` once. It won't return until it reaches the goal symbol followed by end of file.

Comment: Note that identifiers beginning with an underscore and a capital letter are reserved for the implementation for any purpose; you should not create identifiers such as `_LEX_H_` yourself.  In general, and with only a slight overstatement, you should not create identifiers that start with an underscore.  You may use system-defined identifiers that start with underscore, but should not try to create your own.  You'll often get away with it anyway, but it's wise to avoid trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the rule:

```
attribute_pair
    : T_E_TYPE '=' number
```

Your lexer returns `T_EQUAL` but the grammar expects `'='` and the two are not equal.  It was easy for me to spot; when I run the program, I get the report:

```
> opened config file 

error: syntax error, unexpected T_EQUAL, expecting '='
```

So it was remarkably easy to find the problem.  The `yacc` I'm using is actually `bison`:

```
$ yacc --version
bison (GNU Bison) 2.3
…
$
```

When I fixed that, the error changed:

```
> opened config file 

error: syntax error, unexpected T_NUMBER, expecting NUMBER
```

Fixing that involved changing:

```
%token T_E_TYPE T_HOSTID_TYPE T_MAIN_SECTION T_EQUAL T_OPEN_BRACKET T_CLOSE_BRACKET
%token <str> STRING
%token <n> T_NUMBER
```

(Drop T_NUMBER from first line; change `NUMBER` to `T_NUMBER` in third line.)  And also:

```
number
    : T_NUMBER
```

(Change `NUMBER` to `T_NUMBER`.)

With both those changes, you get a successful run (no output other than the open message, but no errors either).

Comment: I have made some changes based on your suggestions and updated the question above.I am still getting another error in [main]

Comment: I hope you didn't damage the original...and thereby partially invalidate my answer.  I'll take a look at what you've got.

Comment: Where does your grammar recognize `T_EOL`? I briefly placed a comment about newlines being the trouble, but I commented in part because I wasn't sure. Then I experimented and it wasn't the newlines that were the trouble (not directly — but they did account for newlines appearing in the output, I think). If you drop the `return T_EOL;` line from the lexer, you should be OK.  Counting line numbers is a good idea.  If you want to keep T_EOL, then you need to insist on a newline after the `]`, so you need `T_EOL` in the rule recognizing a config file section.  Maybe after each attribute pair, too.

Comment: ah I see. You mean config file section show now be ---> T_OPEN_BRACKET T_MAIN_SECTION T_CLOSE_BRACKET T_EOL attribute_list

Comment: Yes, I think so; and `attribute_list: /* Nothing */ : attribute_list attribute_pair T_EOL;` to prevent users writing `name1=value1 name2=value2` on a single line in the config file.  Indeed, you'd need to handle the `T_EOL` somehow because otherwise you can't have them in your file if the lexer returns `T_EOL` when a newline is detected.

Comment: How did you manage to get such detailed error messages. I somehow don't seem to get those?

Comment: my yacc version is 1.9 ? would you recommend using bison?

Comment: If your Yacc is Bison 1.9, then an update is in order.  If your Yacc is byacc 1.9 (originally Berkeley Yacc), then it is more or less up-to-date, but just a different implementation.  I was pleasantly surprised by the clarity of the error message; a blunt 'syntax error' is the traditional treatment.  So, yes, it probably is worth upgrading to Bison 2.x (2.6.2 at least; 2.3 happens to be shipped with Mac OS X 10.10.4 / XCode 6.4, but there are more recent versions).

Comment: You might as well update to bison 3. The extended error messages are generated if you use `-D parse.error=verbose`; you usually also want `-D parse.lac=full`. Both could be specified in you bison file as %define directives. See [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/_0025define-Summary.html#g_t_0025define-Summary)

Comment: Ouch; I see that Bison 2.6.2 was released about 3 years ago — and there have been quite a number of releases since then, and 3.0.4 is available now.  I see no reason not to upgrade to 3.0.4.